# ethers.js AbiCoder returns undefined

Tags: javascript, encode, ethers.js

I am trying to encode function parameters for calldata using AbiCoder function in my nodejs app. But the returned value is undefined.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const abiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder();
const data = abiCoder.encode(["address"], ["0x72c4b017a057505e621c4481ff6ee1aa628373a3"])

console.log(data);
```

```
//console output
undefined
```

I also tried to run the same function in web3.js using encodeParameter function but it still returns the same 'undefined'. Is there a pre setup that I am missing?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I ran your code exatcly, and it produced...

0x00000000000000000000000072c4b017a057505e621c4481ff6ee1aa628373a3

For the encoded data. Not sure that's the output you wanted, but it could be that your ethers import is not properly set up.

Comment: I got the same answer as @NoviceCoder. Did you use `ehters.utils.abiCoder` by accident?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me;

I removed the node modules folder `rm -rf node_modules`, in my `package.json` file, changed the ethers version to `ethers@"5.7.2"`  from  `ethers@"^6.1.0`, and also changed my `"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox"` (if in use) to version `"^2.0.2"` to be in line with the ethers version then after `npm i`.

I guess the new "ethers" version is a bit unstable for now, so I just downgrade.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Works for me, too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use ethers v6 documentation

Now this functionality was moved and can be easily accessed

```
const AbiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder()
```